# Performance with jsonb in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

i have some trouble with my SQL queries on a postgreSQL database.

We are working on table with 300 000 rows.

The first:

```
SELECT DISTINCT jsonb_object_keys("verbatim_verbatim"."meta") AS "meta_key" 
FROM "verbatim_verbatim" 
WHERE "verbatim_verbatim"."group_id" = 'dd1c8016-a0ea-49bb-914b-1c036fb3b0a1'::uuid
```

EXPLAIN :

```
HashAggregate  (cost=25959.68..32449.08 rows=1278700 width=32) (actual time=274.130..274.144 rows=5 loops=1)
  Group Key: jsonb_object_keys(meta)
  Buffers: shared hit=18996 read=2308
  I/O Timings: read=44.623
  ->  Seq Scan on verbatim_verbatim  (cost=0.00..25766.87 rows=77123 width=32) (actual time=0.048..209.216 rows=390000 loops=1)
        Filter: (group_id = 'dd1c8016-a0ea-49bb-914b-1c036fb3b0a1'::uuid)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 263605
        Buffers: shared hit=18996 read=2308
        I/O Timings: read=44.623
Planning time: 103.268 ms
Execution time: 274.385 ms
```

The second:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" 
FROM "verbatim_verbatim" 
WHERE ("verbatim_verbatim"."group_id" = 'dd1c8016-a0ea-49bb-914b-1c036fb3b0a1'::uuid 
       AND "verbatim_verbatim"."themes" IS NOT NULL)
```

EXPLAIN :

```
Aggregate  (cost=25759.21..25759.22 rows=1 width=8) (actual 

time=165.949..165.949 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=19092 read=2212
  I/O Timings: read=52.237
  ->  Seq Scan on verbatim_verbatim  (cost=0.00..25574.06 rows=74059 width=0) (actual time=0.027..161.431 rows=78000 loops=1)
        Filter: ((themes IS NOT NULL) AND (group_id = 'dd1c8016-a0ea-49bb-914b-1c036fb3b0a1'::uuid))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 263605
        Buffers: shared hit=19092 read=2212
        I/O Timings: read=52.237
Planning time: 31.154 ms
Execution time: 166.015 ms
```

with vaccum analyse as suggested in comment:

```
Aggregate  (cost=25758.09..25758.10 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=120.529..120.529 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=20683 read=621
  I/O Timings: read=13.179
  ->  Seq Scan on verbatim_verbatim  (cost=0.00..25574.06 rows=73611 width=0) (actual time=0.027..116.082 rows=78000 loops=1)
        Filter: ((themes IS NOT NULL) AND (group_id = 'dd1c8016-a0ea-49bb-914b-1c036fb3b0a1'::uuid))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 263605
        Buffers: shared hit=20683 read=621
        I/O Timings: read=13.179
Planning time: 59.956 ms
Execution time: 120.595 ms
```

Here my database :

[image]

```
create table verbatim_verbatim
(
    id             serial                   not null
        constraint verbatim_verbatim_pkey
            primary key,
    verbatim_id    varchar(255)             not null,
    date_interview timestamp with time zone not null,
    text           varchar(160000)          not null,
    meta           jsonb                    not null,
    themes         jsonb,
    tonality       varchar(8),
    group_id       uuid                     not null
        constraint verbatim_verbatim_group_id_717c7b4d_fk_verbatim_
            references verbatim_verbatimgroup
            deferrable initially deferred,
    constraint verbatim_verbatim_verbatim_id_group_id_8d53a593_uniq
        unique (verbatim_id, group_id)
);

create index verbatim_verbatim_verbatim_id_7e805bd5
    on verbatim_verbatim (verbatim_id);

create index verbatim_verbatim_verbatim_id_7e805bd5_like
    on verbatim_verbatim (verbatim_id);

create index verbatim_verbatim_meta_89c00a2f
    on verbatim_verbatim (meta);

create index verbatim_verbatim_group_id_717c7b4d
    on verbatim_verbatim (group_id);
```

Do you have some ideas about to optimize these queries :/ ?
Thank for you help !

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you prevent the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well (as formatted text, not as screen shots).

Comment: The question probably has *nothing* to do with JSONB apart from the call to the function. The `WHERE` clause performs simple filtering. If the columns are covered by indexes, the query will be fast, otherwise it will be slow. Executing a `COUNT(*)` on a bunch of rows is always faster than calculating a function for each of those rows. Finally, `DISTINCT` is essentially an `ORDER BY` followed by duplicate elimination. It can be accelerated by indexing, unless it has to work on a function result - the index was built using the raw data, not the function results.

Comment: In PostgreSQL, you can index JSON fields to to accelerate queries, but *this* particular query is trying to flatten and order the contents of the fields. It doesn't use any of the operators that can benefit from JSON indexing. Looks like `meta` is used instead of a proper many-to-many relation. If you intend to run this on 300K rows, you have to use a proper schema. Any other solution will be *slow*

Comment: Thank for all your suggestion & help. In your answer i already learn lot of things !
I added explain @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Both run well under a second (270ms and 166ms). But it seems the statistics aren't up to date on that table as the optimizer expects 1278700  rows for the first query, rather than just 5. That's why it uses a Seq Scan, not the index on `group_id`. Does a `vacuum analyze verbatim_verbatim;` change anything?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: you can't use a set-returning function in an expression for an index.

Comment: Unrelated to your query performance, but why do you have **two** indexes on `(verbatim_id)` and from the screen shot it also seems you have **two** indexes on `(group_id)` as well. Won't make a difference for query performance, but it does make a difference for INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE statements

Comment: Yes, it is because i'm using django framework to work with my db and django do this

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that's why I added `if possible` - I haven't tried to do this before.  `meta` should be its own table.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes we will create new table of meta with your suggestions

Comment: @ValentinGarreau that's because metadata is generally *not* used in direct queries. Separate jobs (typically the full text search indexing job) extracts that data and generates indexes for fast searching by eg tags, categories etc. What does Django use for this? Perhaps there's a mechanism for this? When I started googling for `Django meta` one of the suggestions was `Django meta index`

Comment: @ValentinGarreau if you use Elasticsearch for searching, you should probably query *it*, not PostgreSQL. On the other hand, if fixing statistics gets performance down to milliseconds, you may not have to do anything yet. Fix the statistics first

Comment: we are not using Elasticsearch anymore, the goal was to migrate these data to postgresql :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to compute the correct result, it has no choice to visit all rows where `group_id = 'dd1c8016-a0ea-49bb-914b-1c036fb3b0a1'` so that it can inspect all of the keys.  Since a large chunk of your table meets that condition, this is inevitably going to take some time, and (for your first query anyway) indexes are unlikely to help much.

This looks like some kind of housekeeping operation. Why are you running this so often that you care if it takes a quarter of a second?